# How to call a method in ajax callback function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call a method in the callback function.

```
jsTest.prototype.getTitle = function() {
   thisJS=this

   //the console will returns my object...so it's not undefined.
   console.log(thisJS);


   //codes.....


   //ajax callback function
    ajaxcall.callback=function(data){

        //call the addName method
        thisJS.addName(data, 1);

    };

}


jsTest.prototype.addName=function(data, bool){
    console.log(data);
}
```

I got an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addName' of undefined
```

Are there any ways to solve this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show the code where `getTitle` is called? Does any code in "codes...." access thisJS?

Comment: Try defining `thisJS` as a local variable: `var thisJS = this;`.

Comment: I think prototype is only available for instances created using new ..point out if I am wrong !!  var thisJS= new jsTest() ;

Comment: @Sushanth-- prototype is property of all functions.

Comment: @Matt .. I think prototypes are only available to constructor function created by the new keyword !!

Comment: @Sushanth-- Methods added to the `prototype` are only available to objects created by invoking the constructor with the `new` keyword. I think what Matt is trying to say is that any function object does have a prototype property, regardless of how the function is called.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Oh, you're right then. I was thinking of something.prototype but you meant something.prototype.*

Comment: @Matt .. yup i was confused for a second and that lead to you getting confused ;)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
thisJS=this
```

to this:

```
var thisJS=this
```

Answer (score 0):

to call the method addName, you have to make a reference of that class like in OOP..

if you dont have a jsTest object created then you cant use addName

```
var item = new jsTest();
item.addName(data, 1);
```